# VB6 Picturebox top position

Tags: vb6

In my application I have two picture boxes. Picture1 is aligned to bottom. When I press the mouse button and move the Picture2, the height of Picture1 will change accordingly. Its working fine.

My problem is when I resize the form Picture1 and Picture2 are in different position. Picture2 is not exactly in the top position of Picture1.

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Picture2.Width = Me.ScaleWidth
  Picture2.Top = Picture1.Height + Picture1.Top
End Sub

Private Sub Picture2_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
On Error Resume Next
Screen.MousePointer = 7
If Button = 1 Then
    Picture2.Top = Picture2.Top + (Y)
    Picture1.Height = Me.Height - Picture2.Top - 720
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish. It seems to me that Picture1
is aligned to top, not bottom.

Anyway. Did you mean this?

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Picture2.Width = ScaleWidth
  Picture2.Top = Picture1.Top + Picture1.Height
End Sub

Private Sub Picture2_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  On Error Resume Next

  Screen.MousePointer = 7

  If Button = 1 Then
      Picture2.Top = Picture2.Top + (Y)
      Picture1.Height = Picture2.Top
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I feel this is not right answer because  Picture1.Height = Picture2.Top won't increase the height of Picture1 properly. I am trying to create a bottom panel, which can hold control like SSTab, so when I increase the height of Picture1, the height of SSTab will also get increased.

Answer (score 0):

The picture boxes should stay in the same position wheather you resize the form or not. As @ota milink said, I do not know what you are truly one to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to create bottom panel where I can have controls like SSTab, so when I increase the height of picturebox, SSTab height will also get increased.

Comment: I am using Picturebox as bottom panel